# interrupted system call and socket operation on non-socket Errors, Delphi

Tags: sockets, delphi, httprequest, indy

I use `TidHttp` component to upload too many files to the server , but while the application uploading the files this error's raised to me !

**socket error #10004** interrupted system call and

**socket error #10038** socket operation on non-socket .

Honestly, I don't know what this errors mean !!

this is my code to upload the files !

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  StreamFiles: TIdMultiPartFormDataStream;
  path : string;
begin
  StreamFiles := TIdMultiPartFormDataStream.Create;
  path :=  'D:\example.doc' ;
  try
    StreamFiles.AddFile('upload_file', path, 'text/plain');
    try
    IdHTTP1.Post('http://myserver.com/upload/files', StreamFiles);
    except
     on E: Exception do
       ShowMessage('Error encountered during POST: ' + E.Message);
    end;
  finally
    StreamFiles.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Aren't this IDE-only exceptions? http://www.fredshack.com/docs/indy.html See `Note: All Indy exceptions descend from EIdException. By default, [...]`

Comment: @marioWerner ,OK, Whats about Socket Error #10054 Connection reset by peer???
All these exceptions raised to me , and I have a problem to deal with it !!!